# Dirichlet series experiment - computing the rational coefficient

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, zeta-functions, dirichlet-series, l-functions

Let consider the sequence of numbers $a_n = 0,1,-1,0,1,-1,0,1,-1, ...$ extended periodically ( so it has period $9$, $a_{n+10}=a_n$.  In fact, this is a [Dirichlet character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) $a_n = \chi_9(n)$ modulo 9.

**EDIT** Following Bruno Joyal's suggestion, I tried

$$ \pi \sqrt{3} \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{150,000} \frac{\chi(n)}{n} \approx 0.19244478483 \approx [0, 3, 12092, 3, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 39, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1]$$

suggesting $L(\chi,1) = \pi  \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{1}{3}$ and similarly  $L(\chi,3) = \pi^3 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{4}{81}$.

Yes, I am trying to find generalized Bernoulli numbers for quadratic characters, $\chi: \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \{-1,1\}$.

---

**ORIGINAL** I calculated the *even* Dirichlet series numerically to be

$$ \pi^2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{150,000} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^2} \approx 0.0159743129254 \approx [0, 62, 1, 1, 1, 1, 79, 6, 7, 1]$$

I can guess the that $L(\chi,2) = \pi^2 \cdot \frac{1}{62}$.  The fraction might be $\frac{1}{63}, \frac{2}{125}$.

<del>Which is correct?  And how do we calculate the exact value.</del>  There doesn't seem to be a closed value for these Dirichlet series.  At least, not in $\pi^{2k}\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Dear John : Are you still asking a question?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I wanted to know if there were more special values than $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. On one level, [generalized Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Generalized_Bernoulli_numbers) are my answer with $$ \sum_{a=1}^f \chi(a)\frac{te^{at}}{e^{ft}-1} = \sum_{a=1}^\infty B_{k,\chi} \frac{t^k}{k!}$$  And then you explain there is a very general theory of L-function special values by Deligne, Beilinson, etc.

Comment: That's right. Special values of Dirichlet $L$-series are comparatively well understood. Special values of more complicated $L$-functions, on the other hand...

Comment: @BrunoJoyal All I know are Dirichlet series, since you just change the coefficients.  And I have seen certain multi-zeta functions have special values.  Do you know other good examples?

Comment: Other good examples of $L$-functions?

Comment: @BrunoJoyal a quick google search shows [Artin L-functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin_conjecture_(L-functions)) or [Hecke L-functions](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/lectures.pdf).  These are not subjects I have learned yet.

Comment: Oh yes. I was wondering if you were asking for examples of $L$-functions. (Not quite sure what the question is anymore.)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal My question: `What are the algebraic numbers that appear in Dirichlet L-series?`  Since that question is so well-known, we *could* ask a similar question for other types of L-series... if I was familiar enough with them.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that clears it up. Perhaps you would like to ask this in another question, since this new question is substantially more general than the original question, which was quite specific.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: This answered the question before it was edited.

I don't believe these formulas (namely $L(\chi,2) =  \frac{\pi^2}{62}$ and $L(\chi,4) = \frac{\pi^2 }{1906}$) are true.

First minor issue is that your Dirichlet character (which has a period of $9$ rather than $10$) is not primitive, and is induced from the unique primitive Dirichlet character of conductor $3$, namely the Legendre symbol

$$\chi = (\cdot/3) :(\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z)^\times \to \{\pm 1\}.$$

Your $L$-function is $L(\chi, s)$.

Since $(-1/3)=-1$, $\chi$ is an *odd* quadratic Dirichlet character of conductor $3$, hence the completed $L$-function is

$$\Lambda(\chi, s) = (\pi/3)^{-(s+1)/2}\Gamma((s+1)/2) L(\chi, s)$$

and by Gauss's theorem on the sign of the functional equation, the functional equation is

$$\Lambda(\chi, s) = \Lambda(\chi, 1-s).$$

Because of the presence of the Gamma factor in the definition of $\Lambda(\chi, s)$, it follows that $L(\chi, s)$ has "trivial zeroes" at the odd **negative** integers. Therefore, the functional equation relates the value of $L(\chi, 2n)$ not with $L(\chi, 1-2n)=0$ but with the *derivative* $L'(\chi, 1-2n)$. This is expected to be a transcendental number algebraically independent from $\pi$. The issue is that the even positive integers are not "critical" for $L(\chi, s)$, au sens de Deligne (see Deligne's [Values of $L$-Functions and Periods of Integrals](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~eghate/Deligne.pdf)).

One *can* say something at positive odd integers.  At negative integers, one has

$$L(\chi, 1-n) = -B_{n, \chi}/n \in \mathbf Q$$

where $B_{n, \chi}$ is the generalized Bernoulli number

$$B_{n, \chi} = {3^{n-1}}(B_n(1/3) - B_n(2/3)).$$Using the functional equation we find a formula of the form

$$L(\chi, 2n+1) = \pi^{2n+1} c_n$$

where $c_n \in \mathbf Q$ is an explicit function of $n$ which I'll leave for you to work out (at this point you have all of the ingredients to do so).